# Does tor send data over my server?

Tags: configuration, proxy

Does Tor send data over my server if I installed it? My server has a bandwidth limit so it would be bad if tor runs as a relay.

I've installed the standard tor configuration via apt-get on my Debian 8 server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By default, `tor` acts as a client, and opens a SOCKS5 Proxy on localhost:9050. It will not relay any traffic for the Tor Network unless you specifically set it up in the `/etc/tor/torrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

If one looks at the question in a more general way the answer is Yes and No.

- *Yes*: When you start Tor it will send a request to the directory authority and ask for directory information. Furthermore the software will build a circuit with different relays in the network. So also here some information is sent over the wire.
- *No*: When you think if Tor will act as a relay, the answer is clearly No. If you don't change the initial configuration, Tor will only act as a client and not relay data from other users.